# How to Return an array of objects in a Django model

Tags: python, arrays, django, angularjs

I'm using javascript (plus AngularJS and Restangular) to call a Django endpoint and retrieve an array of proposals. But I can't seem to get my Django syntax right.

**How do I return and array of objects in a given Django model?**

```
def proposal_api(request):
    response = {}
    response['proposal_list'] = Proposal.objects.all()
    return response
```

The Django View above throws the following Attribute error: `'dict' object has no attribute 'status_code'`

Once I receive the array of proposals from the above Django View (with IDs, names, questions, etc...) I'll use AngularJS to display everything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to read up on writing views in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/views/). A view function should return an HTTP response object.

The simplest way would be to just use the `HttpResponse` object from Django like so

```
from django.core import serializers
from django.http import HttpResponse

def proposal_api(request):
    response = {}
    response['proposal_list'] = serializers.serialize("json", Proposal.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(response, content_type="application/json")
```

If you are building an API, however, I would strongly encourage you to checkout [TastyPie](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [Django-Rest-Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

Comment: A vote for Django Rest Framework, it's going to give you a lot of tools that help in developing an API that angular can consume with ease.

Comment: Should also include that should set `response['success'] = True` if using with Ajax.

Comment: That Worked perfectly. Thank you! I should have know I was going to need to serialize the response.